# Can something be moved with light?

Tags: visible-light

I was having the idea that light was probably something that had mass and could push something. I looked it up to find that it does not weight anything.

Then again, I wonder if you could push something with light. Since light can bounce off stuff, I believe that it must be applying some force.

If I gave you an imaginary room where:

- you decide of the gravity force (can be null)
- you decide of the air resistance (can be null)
- you decide of the power of the light source
- you can decide of the weight and size of the object you want to push (can be close to zero but not null)

Given these circumstances, could you manage to push something with light or is there a rule in our room that is missing to do so, without altering the way light itself works?

Comment: Google for "light sails" and "crooke's radiometer" (the latter is an experiment typically shown to middle/high-school students showing light transferring momentum)! Have fun ;)

Comment: I Just read Crooke's Radiometer, was tried to be explained by mometum transfer of light, but that it is actually not the case

Comment: This could also be intersting: : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot

Comment: See optical tweezers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, light has momentum, so it can exert a 'push' on objects. That accounts for the fact that comets have tails that always point away from the Sun.

Sunlight, for example, at the distance of the Earth from the Sun, exerts a force of about 10 micro Newtons per square meter.

You can read about it in detail on Wikipedia here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure

Comment: Marco, your answer would be even better if you had corrected the OP's misunderstanding by explicitly stating that light has a momentum but is still massless. None of the answers so far do, but yours is the accepted one.

Comment: @kkm The question already states that OP knows light is massless: "I looked it up to find that it does not weight anything."

Answer (score 4):

There are actually [optical tweezers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers) – you can levitate and move around small droplets or particles by laser light in the lab. This is used for all kinds of experiments. They work by the momentum transferred when light is refracted.

This even works for biological tissues, and experiments where cells are manipulated by optical tweezers have been done. (Of course, you have to be careful – even an only weakly absorbing material will be heated by high intensity laser light).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you look up light sails, they are propelled by lasers.