# How is light affecting the weight of different colored objects?

Tags: visible-light, weight

I was told [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/665920/278132) that light can move an object and that it pushed against it.

Lets say I have objects of the colors Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Magenta and Cyan, each placed on different balances that are perfectly the same and that have infinite precision.

(And let's be clear, the weight of each object isn't influenced by things such as ink or paint and each object have an equal light source pointing at them from above)

My question:

**If their weight aren't the same, how would the be ranked ?**

**If you closed all the light, would their weight be equal ?** (if they weren't before)

In the same line of idea, if you were in a room with no gravity or air resistance and you pointed 2 equal light sources on a white and a black piece of paper of the same size, **which one would reach the wall of the room first ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colored objects absorb all the  other colors  and reflect what is called there color. Since absorbing means the object gets the impulse of the light. reflecting means getting double th ampuls . One gets a very slight advantage from cyan and the ranking would be from cyan to red.
Since the white cloth reflects more again it reaches the wall first, but better make it an aluminum foil for better reflecting.